# execute remote command on remote windows via linux while escaping quotes

Tags: bash, quoting

On windows following command works fine.

```
typeperf -sc 1 -si 1 "\\MYSERVER\Forefront TMG Web Proxy\Cache Hit Ratio (%)"

"01/04/2017 13:28:57.721","14.000000"
```

I want to execute above query from my linux box. This is what I am using

```
root@linux:/temp# winexe -U domain/admin%password //MYSERVER "typeperf -sc 1 -si 1 "\\MYSERVER\Forefront TMG Web Proxy\Cache Hit Ratio (%)"

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can I query above command from my Linux to get required result which is "14.000000"

Comment: Count your double quotes.

Comment: I am really dumb. can you please give some more info or example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3776858/cyrus) indicated in comments, you have a un-balanced double-quote, try this below.

```
winexe -U domain/admin%"password" //MYSERVER 'typeperf -sc 1 -si 1 "\\MYSERVER\Forefront TMG Web Proxy\Cache Hit Ratio (%)"'
```

I guess it is acceptable to wrap the outer commands within single-quotes and inner command within double-quotes.

Comment: winexe -U domain/admin%"password" //MYSERVER 'typeperf -sc 1 -si 1 "\\MYSERVER\Forefront TMG Web Proxy\Cache Hit Ratio (%)"'
RESULTING IN 


"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\101.11.11.6\Forefront TMG Web Proxy\Cache Hit Ratio (%)"
"01/04/2017 19:04:14.617","14.000000"
Exiting, please wait...


The command completed successfully.